# Insert data to MySQL - Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am parsing XML and trying to insert it value to mysql database.(I start only with typename)

XML looks like:

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
<movie title="Enemy Behind">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2003</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Transformers">
   <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1989</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <stars>8</stars>
   <description>A schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
   <movie title="Trigun">
   <type>Anime, Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Vash the Stampede!</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Ishtar">
   <type>Comedy</type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>2</stars>
   <description>Viewable boredom</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```

My code looks like:

```
# Print detail of each movie.
for movie in movies:
    print ("*****Movie*****")
    if movie.hasAttribute("title"):
        print ("Title: %s" % movie.getAttribute("title"))
        titleName = movie.getAttribute("title")
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Enemy Behind')")
    type = movie.getElementsByTagName('type')[0]
    print ("Type: %s" % type.childNodes[0].data)
    with con:
        typeName = type.childNodes[0].data
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(type) VALUES(typeName)")
    format = movie.getElementsByTagName('format')[0]
    print ("Format: %s" % format.childNodes[0].data)
    rating = movie.getElementsByTagName('rating')[0]
    print ("Rating: %s" % rating.childNodes[0].data)
    description = movie.getElementsByTagName('description')[0]
    print ("Description: %s" % description.childNodes[0].data)
```

Error I get:

```
Title: Enemy Behind
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/....MyPython.py", line 35, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(type) VALUES(typeName)")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 220, in execute
Type: War, Thriller
```

Is there anyone who can help me figure out where the problem is? I am completly new to this so I'm totally lost

Comment: cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(type) VALUES(%s)" % typeName) ?

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Enemy Behind')")` should be switched to `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES(titleName)")`  You are not sure if that is working because you hardcoded it.

Comment: It appears to be getting further than that. Even if it's a hardcoded value he should be fine unless he has a unique constrained on his table for that column.

Comment: In database column is varchar(255), and default NULL, i see no problems in this :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a space in the type `War, Thriller`. Try changing this line to 
 `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(type) VALUES(typeName)")` to `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(type) VALUES('typeName')")` to include `''` in the query to contain the typeName.

**Example**

<sup>Assuming type is a `char`, `varchar`, etc</sup>

This SQL, `insert into Writers(type) values(my string)` will fail because the string value we're inserting is not enclosed by quotes.

However, 
`insert into Writers(type) values('my string')` should work because we've enclosed the string value we are inserting by quotes.

Comment: Hi AndrewSmiley, this is going to insert string to my database because python doesnt know it's variabile. So like this I have type=typeName in database

Comment: I'm sorry, but you lost me there. If you're saying typeName is the value that you're inserting into the Type column then yes, you'd be correct. Can you upload the full stacktrace?